# PHP - CURL using HTTPS

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get Json Data from a **https** url.

I have tested and working code to do just this for **http** but I am yet to find a working version for **https**. This needs to be secure code.

This is my **http** version that works:

```
<?php
$key = "admin"; //user
$secret = "admin"; //pass
$api_ep = "http://$Hostname:$Port/$address";


if ($key && $secret){
$curl_opts = array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array("Accept: application/json"),
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>false,
  CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
  CURLOPT_POST=>false,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
  CURLOPT_USERPWD=>$key.":".$secret,
  CURLOPT_URL=> $api_ep  
);
}
   
function disp($opts,$var){
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
  $raw_resp = curl_exec($ch);
//  $array_resp = json_decode($raw_resp);

  //print_r($array_resp);
  print_r($raw_resp);
  curl_close($ch);
//$array = json_decode($raw_resp, true);
//print_r($array_resp);
//disp_table($array_resp, $var);
}

disp($curl_opts,$Type);
?>
```

Comment: You probably have to set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` options.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any sensitive data you can try setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `FALSE`

Else you will have to verify the certificate.

Since Curl doesn't have built-in root certificates. You need to explicitly point it to a cacert.pem file:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cert/file/cacert.pem');
```

Without this, curl cannot verify the certificate sent back via ssl. This same root certificate file can be used every time you use SSL in curl.

You can get the `cacert.pem` file here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

**Note:**

Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false allows for `man-in-the-middle-attacks`. rmckay at webaware dot com dot au warns for this on [nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and gives an alternative solution that works: downloading a CA root certificate bundle at the curl website and saving it on your server. See at the given site, scroll down to the user comments

Answer (score 0):

This code below works for https.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $basicAuthUrl);
    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-length: 29';
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $header[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $keyAndSecretEncoded;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to disable SSL verification.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Curl SSL fails to verify self signed certificates and hence, you will not be able to connect with https hosts if they are using self signed certificates.

```
function disp($opts,$var){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
  $raw_resp = curl_exec($ch);
  print_r($raw_resp);
  curl_close($ch);
}
```